# Scheduler will not run a scheduled job

Tags: go

I am unable to get prprpus scheduler library with Go to work. I was trying to recreate the functionality of JavaScript's `setinterval`.  The for loop should not block the scheduled job right?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/prprprus/scheduler"
)
func keepAlive2() {
    fmt.Println("Keep alive 2")
}
func main() {
    s, schedulerErr := scheduler.NewScheduler(1000)
    if schedulerErr != nil  {
        panic(schedulerErr)
    }
    s.Every().Second(1).Do(keepAlive2)
    for {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Busy-wait tight loops like

```
for {
}
```

will not allow other goroutines execute. It will not yield. If you need to wait, use one of the synchronization primitives, such as:

```
ch:=make(chan struct{})
<- ch
```

Comment: The example given in question works and scheduling is also working for me with goroutines (I am using golang in windows). But the same code i tried in go playground is notworking . Any guess ?

Comment: Im just learning go and this looks like a common idiom of the language. So If I replace the for loop with this it creates a channel that I never receive from and thus locking up the main thread? Am I interpreting this correctly?

Comment: @cslrnr because of exactly what's explained in this answer.

Comment: @cslrnr if go runtime schedules the main goroutine and the new goroutine created by your scheduler in two different OS threads, then it will work. If go runtime schedules both goroutines to use the same OS thread, the busy-wait loop will not yield, and the second goroutine will never execute.

Comment: @TommieJones the difference is: <- ch puts the calling goroutine to sleep, letting other goroutines run. With `for {}` the calling goroutine executes the for loop and never yields (at least for the time being).